# Nonzero polynomials of degree $n$ in $D[x]$ have at most $n$ distinct roots in $D$, assuming $D$ is only an integral ring.

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, polynomials, ring-theory

Suppose $c_i,i=0,1,\cdots,n$ are distinct elements in an **integral ring** $D$ (that is, $a,b\in D$ and $a,b\ne 0$ implies $ab\ne 0$, but no assumption about commutativity is made), $f(x)\in D[x]$ and $\deg f\le n,\, f(c_i)=0,i =0,1,\cdots,n$, prove that $f(x)\equiv 0$.

How should I start? $D$ is not even an integral domain, so I am not even sure whether $(x-c_i)\mid f(x)$. (And what use to make of it even if it does hold? I don't think we can make a contradiction by simply claiming that $(x-c_0)\cdots(x-c_{n})\mid f(x)$ since Euclidean algorithm isn't available here).

What surprises me is the solution book uses Vandermonde matrix! It says that suppose $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+\cdots+a_nx^n$, then we have 
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & c_0 & \cdots & c_0^n\\
1& c_1 & \cdots & c_1^n \\
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
1 & c_n & \cdots & c_n^n
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_0\\a_1\\ \vdots \\a_n \end{bmatrix}=\vec 0
$$
I really have no idea why $D$ can be treated as if it were a field...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $f(x) = a_m x^m + \ldots + a_0$, $a_m \neq 0$, $m \leq n$ be the polynomial in $D[x]$.  If we evaluate $f(c_i)$ for each $i$ we get a sequence of equations:

$$f(c_0) = a_m c_0^m + a_{m-1} c_0^{m-1} + \ldots a_0$$
$$f(c_1) = a_m c_1^m + a_{m-1} c_1^{m-1} + \ldots a_0$$
$$\ldots$$
$$f(c_n) = a_m c_n^m + a_{m-1} c_n^{m-1} + \ldots a_0$$

These equations are exactly those equations described by the matrix product:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
c_0^m & c_0^{m-1} & \ldots & 1 \\ 
c_1^m & c_1^{m-1} & \ldots & 1 \\ 
\vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots\\
c_n^m & c_n^{m-1} & \ldots & 1 \\ 
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix} a_m\\a_{m-1}\\ \vdots \\a_0 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} f(c_0)\\f(c_1)\\ \vdots \\f(c_n) \end{bmatrix}
$$

As each $c_i$ is distinct, we know that the determinant of the matrix is nonzero, and thus it's a map from $D^m \to D^n$ (this is a $D$-module map, or a $D$-linear map.  Not a general linear map between vector spaces) with a trivial kernel.  (NOTE: that a nonzero determinant means the map has a trivial still holds in the case over $D$ instead of a general field is true, but you should verify it) As $f(c_i)=0$ for all i, we know that the image of the $a$ vector lands in the kernel. But the kernel is trivial, so that $a$ vector must be 0.  Therefore the polynomial $f$ is zero.

Comment: You are assuming $D$ is commutative, which I think is what the author intended to mean ( even though he only defined $D$ as an integral ring instead of a domain), so add one for your answer, thank you!

Comment: I am not assuming $D$ is commutative.  But I might have swapped the order of multiplication around because I am sloppy.  The result still holds whether or not $D$ is commutative.

Comment: in the case of non-commutativity, is it even true that $ax=xa$.

Comment: it might be true, depending on which $x$ and $a$, but in general, no.  But that is OK, so long as the coefficients of $f$ are on the same side of the indeterminate $x$.    Then you define the matrix multiplication so its consistent with evaluation of the polynomial, and everything follows. The point is that in a noncom ring, you are OK so long as you do everything all on the right side.  or all on the left side.  just don't go swapping the two around.

Comment: "*The result still holds whether or not D is commutative.*" I have serious doubts. Over the quaternion algebra (which is a division ring), the polynomial $X^2+1$ has infinitely many roots.

Comment: you are right, that example alone is a counterexample to my assertion.  I obviously haven't though about it deeply enough.